# URL keyword vs URL readibility

Tags: url, seo

this question is about SEO in URL naming, I just want to know is SEO really weight much more than user experience? What you guys will see as limit to how far SEO should go as ruining people's experience. Just like for this example, I have a page that contain information about art contest that is running or have run in my website.

Which URL is better?

example.com/contest/{contest-id}/{name-of-contest}

or

example.com/online-graphic-design-contest/{contest-id}/{name-of-contest}

Is keyword stuffing in url for keyword such as 'online', 'graphic', 'design' and 'contest' so much more important in SEO, than having a short more readable URL such as the first one?

Comment: I think it really depends. In this case, the second alternative is cool (specially if there are other contests in that online-design section) it definitely helps SEO and it doesn't seem to ruin the user experience too much. But if you take to the extreme like `example.com/super-duper-contests/awesome-graphics/top-notch-designers/this-is-what-you-are-looking-for/{contest-id}/{name-of-contest}` i'd stick with the first one.

Answer (score 2):

The best way to think about SEO these days is through the perspective of the user, firstly, and then through the search engine perspective. I would argue that your second URL is much better for both cases. It's more descriptive to the user (we have an "online graphic design contest") and also to search engines.

Google has made it apparent that their focus is on providing content that is relevant to the user, and the best way to be relevant is with content that is descriptive and fits with what your users are searching for. I don't think you're keyword stuffing if you're using a single natural language phrase in the URL to describe the content of the page. That portion of the URL should also match your page title, and header tags on the page, etc., etc.

Here are some useful resources:
http://static.googleusercontent.com/media/www.google.com/en/us/webmasters/docs/search-engine-optimization-starter-guide.pdf
http://linchpinseo.com/user-focused-seo-redefining-what-search-engine-optimization-is